# Foreman Gem with Sunspot does not start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, foreman

Anyone has issues with the foreman gem ( loads your rake tasks and deamons from 1 command ) with sunspot gem? I always have to manually start sunspot because Foreman does say it loads it but it isn't

Always have to manually run this command to get sunspot/solr to start:

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
```

anyone knows a way to make it load true foreman?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding

```
search: bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run
```

to your Procfile should start Solr when running foreman. It requires processes to be start in foreground. rake sunspot:solr:start immediately exits after starting Solr in background and foreman assumes that the process died.

Comment: Great thx alot coudent find this antwhere how did you figured this out? Thx

Comment: I had a look on how foreman starts the web servers after noticing that it doesn't like background tasks. Actually it makes sense as there would be not way to know the state of the process otherwise.